# apply function to cloned row fields asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a form in an asp.net mvc. The form is dynamic and allows users to add more fields - in fact it's used to add items to an invoice. I have an extremely low knowledge of javascript, but in these conditions I've bumped into it and all I've built so far I did following tutorials and other questions marked on this website. 
To add rows to invoice, I'm cloning the row. I have a function that accesses the controller and gets the price of the item that is selected in the Article dropdown. Controller returns the price and the value is added to the "Pret" field. It works well for the first row, but when I add new row and make a selection of an article in the new row, it alters the "Pret" value of the first row. Below you can find the code I'm using in the view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Iesiri";
}

<div class="row wrapper border-bottom white-bg page-heading">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h2>Iesire noua</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="title-action">
            @Html.ActionLink("Inapoi", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">

    <div class="row">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Iesiri", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "iesiri" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="tabs-container">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-1"> Detalii document</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-2"> Articole / Servicii</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div id="tab-1" class="tab-pane active">
                            <div class="panel-body">

                                <fieldset class="form-horizontal">

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="FormTypeID">Tip document:</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <select class="chosen-select" id="TipDocument" name="TipDocument" required="true" tabindex="2">
                                                <option value="Factura">Factura</option>
                                                <option value="Bon de casa">Bon de casa</option>
                                                <option value="Factura simplificata">Factura simplificata</option>
                                                <option value="Taxare inversa">Taxare inversa</option>
                                                <option value="Fara drept de deducere (partial)">Fara drept de deducere (partial)</option>
                                                <option value="Fara drept de deducere (integral)">Fara drept de deducere (integral)</option>
                                                <option value="Servicii art.311-312">Servicii art.311-312</option>
                                                <option value="Borderou de achizitii">Borderou de achizitii</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="TipDocument" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="FormTypeID">Seria</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            @Html.DropDownList("SeriaID", (SelectList)ViewBag.SeriaID, new { @class = "chosen-select", @tabindex = "2", @required = "false" })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SeriaID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NrDocument, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NrDocument)
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NrDocument, new { @class = "form-control" })

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="FormTypeID">Client</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            @Html.DropDownList("ClientID", (SelectList)ViewBag.ClientID, new { @class = "chosen-select", @tabindex = "2", @required = "false" })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClientID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    @*
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VatCollection, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                                <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
                                                    <input data-val="true" data-val-required="Camp obligatoriu - TVA I" id="VatCollection" type="checkbox" name="VatCollection" value="true">
                                                    <label for="VatCollection">
                                                        Da
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    *@
                                    <div class="form-group" id="data_document">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataDocument, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <div class="input-group date">
                                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span><input id="DataDocument" type="text" class="form-control" name="DataDocument">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group" id="data_scadenta">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ScadentaDocument, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <div class="input-group date">
                                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span><input id="ScadentaDocument" type="text" class="form-control" name="ScadentaDocument">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </fieldset>


                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="tab-2" class="tab-pane">
                            <div class="panel-body">

                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table class="table table-stripped table-bordered">

                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>
                                                    Gestiune
                                                </th>
                                                <th>
                                                    Articol
                                                </th>
                                                <th>
                                                    Cantitate
                                                </th>
                                                <th>
                                                    Pret
                                                </th>

                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr class="data-wrapper">
                                                <td>
                                                    @Html.DropDownList("GestiuniID", (SelectList)ViewBag.GestiuniID, new { @class = "chosen-select", @style = "width:100px;", @tabindex = "2", @required = "false" })
                                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GestiuniID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @Html.DropDownList("ArticolID", (SelectList)ViewBag.ArticolID, new { @class = "chosen-select", @style = "width:100px;", @tabindex = "2", @required = "false" })
                                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ArticolID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Cantitate, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cantitate)
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Pret, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pret)
                                                </td>


                                            </tr>

                                        </tbody>

                                    </table><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary add-new-data"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger rem-new-data"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                                        <button class="btn btn-success " id="submit" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>&nbsp;Finalizeaza</button>
                                        @Html.ActionLink("Renunta", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn btn-white" })
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        }
    </div>

</div>



@section Styles {
    @Styles.Render("~/plugins/awesomeCheckboxStyles")
    @Styles.Render("~/plugins/clockpickerStyles")
    @Styles.Render("~/plugins/dateRangeStyles")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/plugins/iCheck/iCheckStyles")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/plugins/chosen/chosenStyles")
    @Styles.Render("~/plugins/switcheryStyles")
    @Styles.Render("~/plugins/jasnyBootstrapStyles")
    @Styles.Render("~/plugins/nouiSliderStyles")
    @Styles.Render("~/plugins/dataPickerStyles")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/plugins/ionRangeSlider/ionRangeStyles")
    @Styles.Render("~/plugins/imagecropperStyles")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/plugins/colorpicker/colorpickerStyles")
    @Styles.Render("~/plugins/select2Styles")
    @Styles.Render("~/plugins/touchSpinStyles")
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/plugins/iCheck")
    @Scripts.Render("~/plugins/dataPicker")
    @Scripts.Render("~/plugins/ionRange")
    @Scripts.Render("~/plugins/nouiSlider")
    @Scripts.Render("~/plugins/jasnyBootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/plugins/switchery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/plugins/chosen")
    @Scripts.Render("~/plugins/knob")
    @Scripts.Render("~/plugins/imagecropper")
    @Scripts.Render("~/plugins/colorpicker")
    @Scripts.Render("~/plugins/clockpicker")
    @Scripts.Render("~/plugins/dateRange")
    @Scripts.Render("~/plugins/select2")
    @Scripts.Render("~/plugins/touchSpin")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //$('.summernote').summernote();

            var date = new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10);
            document.getElementById("DataDocument").value = date;
            document.getElementById("ScadentaDocument").value = date;

            $('#data_document .input-group.date').datepicker({
                defaultDate:'now',
                format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                defaultDate: new Date(),
                todayBtn: "linked",
                keyboardNavigation: false,
                forceParse: false,
                calendarWeeks: true,
                autoclose: true
            });
            $('#data_scadenta .input-group.date').datepicker({
                defaultDate: 'now',
                format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                defaultDate: new Date(),
                todayBtn: "linked",
                keyboardNavigation: false,
                forceParse: false,
                calendarWeeks: true,
                autoclose: true
            });



        });

        $("#FormTypeID").prop("selectedIndex", -1);


        jQuery(function ($) {

            var clone = $("table tr.data-wrapper:first").clone(true);

            $("#TipDocument").chosen({ width: "100%" });
            $("#SeriaID").chosen({ width: "100%" });
            $("#ClientID").chosen({ width: "100%" });
            $("#GestiuniID").chosen({ width: "100%" });
            $("#ArticolID").chosen({ width: "100%" });

            $('select.GestiuniID').chosen({ width: "100%" });
            $('select.ArticolID').chosen({ width: "100%" });

            $('.chosen-select').on("chosen:showing_dropdown", function () {

                $(this).parents("div").css("overflow", "visible");

            });





            $('body').on('click', '.add-new-data', function () {                
                var ParentRow = $("table tr.data-wrapper").last();
                clone.clone(true).insertAfter(ParentRow);
                $('tr.data-wrapper:last select').chosen({ width: "100%" });          
            });

            $('body').on('click', '.rem-new-data', function () {
                $('tr.data-wrapper').last().remove();
            });

            $('body').on('change', '#ArticolID', function (e, params) {
                getPrice(e.target.value, $('#DataDocument').val());
            });

            function getPrice(id, date) {
                var data = { id: id, date: date };
                $.get('/Iesiri/GetPrice/', 
                    data, 
                    function (response) { 
                        $('#Pret').last().val(response[0].PretVanzare);
                    },
                    'json' 
                );
            }


        });



    </script>
}
```

Help would be very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it... the answer was very simple. I had to change this:

```
$('#Pret').last().val(response[0].PretVanzare);
```

into this:

```
$('tr:last td:last #Pret').val(response[0].PretVanzare);
```